# Unable to use schemaRegistry in reactor kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, project-reactor, confluent-schema-registry, reactor-kafka

I am tying to setup kafka consumer using reactor kafka . Producer is integrated with kafka schema registry

```
    @Value("${spring.kafka.schemaRegistryUrls}")
    private String schemaRegistryEnvVarValue;


 @Bean
    public ReceiverOptions<String, MyProto> kafkaReceiverOptionsFloor(
            KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

        final Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerProperties =
                kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        for (Map.Entry<String, KafkaProperties.Consumer> entry :
                kafkaConsumerPropertiesConfig.getConsumer().entrySet()) {
            if (kafkaTopics.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                kafkaConsumerProperties.putAll(entry.getValue().buildProperties());
            }
        }
        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryEnvVarValue);
        final ReceiverOptions<String, MyProto> basicReceiverOptions =
                ReceiverOptions.<String, MyProto>create(
                                kafkaConsumerProperties)
                        .withValueDeserializer(new MyProtoDeserializer())
                        // disabling auto commit, since we are managing committing once
                        // record is
                        // processed
                        .commitInterval(Duration.ZERO)
                        .commitBatchSize(0);

        kafkaConsumerProperties.forEach((k, v) -> log.debug("k2 {} v2 {}", k, v));

        return basicReceiverOptions
                .subscription(kafkaTopicsFloor)
                .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsAssigned {}", partitions))
                .addRevokeListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsRevoked {}", partitions));
    }


  @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, MyProto>
            reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate(
                    ReceiverOptions<String, MyProto>
                            kafkaReceiverOptions) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(kafkaReceiverOptions);
    }
```

I am getting exception as *Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).*
Its able to parse in my Unit tests (without schema registry)

Looks like schemaregistry is not being used . what am i doing wrong here .

Deserializer looks like below

```
@Slf4j
public class MyProtoDeserializer implements Deserializer<MyProto> {
    public MyProtoDeserializer() {}

    /**
     * Deserializes the data to my_proto from byte array.
     *
     * @param topic
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public MyProto deserialize(final String topic, final byte[] data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // TODO: Use schemaregistry and kpow
      
        try {
            return MyProto.getDefaultInstance()
                    .getParserForType()
                    .parseFrom(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.debug("Exception in MyProto parse {}", ex.getMessage());
            return MyProto.getDefaultInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor isn't the issue.

`schema.registry.url` is only a property of the Confluent Deserializer class. You are not implementing `configure` function in the Deserializer, therefore you are ignoring that property. Similarly, directly calling `parseFrom` isn't using any HTTP client to interact with a Registry.

Import the library, rather than write your own

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-protobuf-serializer/7.4.0

Also, this is how to auto configure Spring Boot with that property

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer
      properties:
        "[schema.registry.url]": http://...
```

ref https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties